# Is there a way to initialize a PHPUnit Test class template?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Lets say I have a class named Foo in a file named Foo.php  and I want to unit test it, Is there a command like 'phpunit init Foo.php' that will create a file named FooTest.php with empty test functions for every function in the Foo.php class file ?

Comment: I don't believe phpunit has one built in. A quick search shows there is at least one tool out there that will do this (though it is marked as dead). Do some searching around till you find something that suits. Or write your own :)

Comment: Yeah I think i will write my own, wanted to ask just in case

Comment: Also feel free to make it open source licensed and on github ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no test generator feature in PHPUnit.

There used to be, it was removed in version 3.7.0.

> Removed deprecated `--skeleton-class` and `--skeleton-test` switches. The functionality is now provided by the `phpunit-skelgen` command of the `PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator` package. — [3.7.0 Changelog](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/ChangeLog-for-PHPUnit-3.7#phpunit-370)

The [PHPUnit Skeleton Generator](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator) is no longer maintained.